# Randomly accessing a compressed file without using ZipFile (since ZipFile has a major bug)

Tags: java, compression, zip, zipinputstream

I know, I know, who would want to compress or uncompressed large files in java. Completely unreasonable. For the moment suspend disbelief and assume I have a good reason for uncompressing a large zip File.

Issue 1: [ZipFile](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) has a [bug (bug # 6280693)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=9dea65953f1524bbebc370dbf7a?bug_id=6280693), sun has fixed this in java 1.6 (Mustang). The fix isn't isn't helpful as our software needs to support java 1.4. The bug, as I understand it, works like this. When the following code is run, Java allocates a chunk of memory large enough to hold the entire file.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/tmp/myFile.zip");
```

If /tmp/myFile.zip is 4gb, java allocates 4gb. This causes an out of a heap exception. A heap size of +4gb is unfortunately not an acceptable solution. =(

Solution to issue 1: Use [ZipInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), to deal with the file as a stream and thus reduce and control the memory footprint.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("/tmp/myFile.zip")
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(fs);

ZipEntry ze = zipIn.getNextEntry();

while (ze != null){
  while ((int cr = zipIn.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1) 
    System.out.write(buf, 0, len);
  ze = zipIn.getNextEntry();
}
```

Issue 2: I would like access the ZipEntries randomly. That is, I would like to only uncompress one ZipEntry, without having to search through the entire stream. Currently I am building up a list of zipEntries, called zes:

```
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream("/tmp/myFile.zip");
        
        ZipEntry ze = zin.getNextEntry();
        List<ZipEntry> zes = new ArrayList<ZipEntry>();

        while(ze!=null){
            zes.add(ze);
            ze = zin.getNextEntry();
        }
```

Then when I need to uncompress a particular zipEntry I iteratorate through all the zipEntries until I find the matching zipEntry, which I then uncompress.

```
        ZipEntry ze = in.getNextEntry();
        while (! ze.getName().equals(queryZe.getName())){
            ze = zin.getNextEntry();
        }
        
        int cr;

        while ((cr = zin.read(buf)) > -1) 
            System.out.write(buf, 0, cr);
```

Quertion: ZipFile has the ability to randomly access ZipEntries.

```
new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry));
```

How can I get this same ability without using ZipFile?

Note that ZipInputStream has some rather [strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826390/zipinputstream-doesnt-report-actual-i-e-compressed-bytes-read) [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275/reading-from-a-zipinputstream-into-a-bytearrayoutputstream/69489#69489).

Especially good documentation on java and ZipFiles can be found here:

http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html

**Notes on switching replacing sun ZipFile with apache commons ZipFile as suggested in the answers:**

1. Sun's [ZipFile.entries()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) always returns the ZipEntries in the order in which they occur in the file, whereas apache commons [ZipFile.getEntries()](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile.html) returns the entries in random order. This caused an interesting bug, because some code was assuming that the entries would be "in order".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task, you may want to look at [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/), [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/), or [TrueZip](https://truezip.dev.java.net/). All of these should be Java 1.4 compatible, and probably support the features you need.

Comment: 23 Mb only for archives support? Seriosly? My whole app with 15+ activities weights 4 Mb. I think it's a disrespection for users to use so heavy apps for trivial tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/), which works with 1.4+, but I don't know if it exposes the same bug under the hood or not.

Comment: It doesn't? http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile.html

Comment: Then what is this? http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile.html